# Is structured streaming the only option for python + spark 3.1.1 + kafka?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

The [doc for streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) integration doesn't contain python section. Does this mean python is not supported?

On the other hand, in [structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), Kafka put everything into one or two columns (key and value) and sql operations have a little sense here out of the box. The only way to introduce pure Python processing are UDFs, which are expensive. Is this true?

Comment: Pyspark, technically, can import any of the JVM Spark libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people are using Structured Streaming with Kafka and don't have problems.  The Spark is putting everything into the two columns for a reason that it's how the Kafka works (and other systems, like, EventHubs, Kinesis, etc.) - the both key & value are just binary blobs from Kafka point of view, and Kafka doesn't know anything about what is inside - it's up to the developer to decide what to put inside that blob - plain string, Avro, JSON, etc.

Typical workflow with Kafka & Structured Streaming looks as following (everything is done via Spark APIs, without need to use UDFs, and is very efficient):

- read data with `spark.readStream`
- cast `value` (and maybe `key`) into specific type, like, `string` if JSON is used, or leave as binary if Avro is used
- The depending on format:

  - if JSON is used, use [from_json function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) to decode string into Struct
  - if Avro is used, use [from_avro function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.avro.functions.from_avro)
- Promote fields from payload into top-level of the dataframe

For example, for JSON as value:

```py
json_schema = ... # put structure of your JSON payload here
df = spark.read\
  .format("kafka")\
  .options(**kafka_options)\
  .load()\
  .withColumn("value", F.col("value").cast("string"))\
  .withColumn("json", F.from_json(F.col("value"), json_schema)\
  .select("json.*", "*")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have reached this stage already. But what next? How to perform computations/aggregations on data if I want to do something custom?

Comment: It depends on what is "custom".  Spark streaming supports aggregations as well (not everything but still), but you need to take care of the watermarks, etc.: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-operations---selection-projection-aggregation If you need to do something that isn't supported then you can go down to the `foreachBatch`.  If you need to use UDFs, then it's better to use Pandas UDFs that are much faster than "normal" UDFs

Comment: I also recommend to get this book: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/stream-processing-with/9781491944233/ - it covers many use cases